# Why can't I deploy from Team Foundation Server, but I can from Visual Studio with the same publish profile?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, networking, deployment, tfs

I am currently using my install of Visual Studio 2015 to deploy my builds to the network drives we update with my program. I have a publish profile set up and it has worked for months.

Our company recently bought team foundation server, and I was able to set up the build agent. Once I had all my code checked in, the build server was green, visual studio 2015 was installed on the TFS server, and my build worked just fine. It deposited the build to the normal local directory on the server, and everything worked great.

So then I was wanting to take full advantage of the tfs deployment feature. I set up my msbuild arguments for deploy on build. But every time it gets to the deploy part of the build, it fails. It gives me the error "Error MSB3191: Unable to create directory". And it said the specific reason was wrong username or password. I have access to this folder, I can publish to it directly from visual studio every time.

The service account that is running the build server has access to this folder. The local shadow account for the service account has access to this folder. All the accounts involved in the project in tfs have full rights to do everything imaginable. But still, it will not let me deploy my project to a this network drive path from the server where tfs is running, using the deploy on build method, or any other method. I am beyond confused at this point.

EDIT:

My msbuild arguments are:
/t:BUILD /t:Publish /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile="TestThingWeb"

The publish profile definitely works. The deploy on build using tfs does not.

This is the entire log file that I am getting. I had to delete a bunch of crap to get it to fit in this window, but the error message is code boxed.

---

Starting: Get sources

---

Syncing repository: TestWebProject (TFVC)
Workspace Name: ws_6_5;DEPFOUNDATION\DEPTFSBDAGT
tf get /version:C271
Done syncing repository TestWebProject to version C271 (workspace version C271)

---

Running tasks

---

---

Starting task: NuGet restore ***.sln

---

Set workingFolder to default: C:\DEPBuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.17
Executing the powershell script: C:\DEPBuildAgent\tasks\NuGetInstaller\0.1.17\NuGetInstaller.ps1
C:\DEPBuildAgent\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe restore "C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1.sln"  -NonInteractive
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.

---

Finishing task: NuGetInstaller

---

---

Starting task: Build solution ***.sln

---

Build started 8/2/2016 12:08:31 PM.
     1>Project "C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1.sln" on node 1 (BUILD;Publish target(s)).
     1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
         Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
     1>Project "C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1.sln" (1) is building "C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
     2>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
       Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
       CoreCompile:
       Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
       _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory:
       Skipping target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
       _CopyAppConfigFile:
       Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
       CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
         TestWebProject1 -> C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1\bin\TestWebProject1.dll
       ValidatePublishProfileSettings:
         Validating PublishProfile(TestThingWeb) settings.
       ValidateGlobalPackageSetting:
         $(PackageAsSingleFile) is True
         $(PackageFileName) is obj\Release\Package\TestWebProject1.zip. Validating...
       CollectFilesFromIntermediateAssembly:
         Gather all files from Project items @(IntermediateAssembly). Adding:
         bin\TestWebProject1.dll to bin\TestWebProject1.dll
       CollectFilesFromContent:
         Gather all files from Project items @(Content). Adding:
         Content\bootstrap.css;Content\bootstrap.min.css;favicon.ico;fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg;Global.asax;Content\Site.css;Scripts\ai.0.15.0-build58334.js;Scripts\ai.0.15.0-build58334.min.js;Scripts\bootstrap.js;Scripts\bootstrap.min.js;ApplicationInsights.config;Scripts\jquery-1.10.2.js;Scripts\jquery-1.10.2.min.js;Scripts\jquery.validate.js;Scripts\jquery.validate.min.js;Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js;Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js;Scripts\modernizr-2.6.2.js;Scripts\respond.js;Scripts\respond.min.js;Scripts_references.js;Web.config;Web.Debug.config;Web.Release.config;Views\Web.config;Views_ViewStart.cshtml;Views\Shared\Error.cshtml;Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml;Views\Home\About.cshtml;Views\Home\Contact.cshtml;Views\Home\Index.cshtml;Views\Account_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml;Views\Account\ConfirmEmail.cshtml;Views\Account\ExternalLoginConfirmation.cshtml;Views\Account\ExternalLoginFailure.cshtml;Views\Account\ForgotPassword.cshtml;Views\Account\ForgotPasswordConfir...
       CollectFilesFromIntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath:
         Gather all files from Project output (IntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath). Adding:
       CollectFilesFromReference:
         Gather all files from Project items @(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths,ReferenceComWrappersToCopyLocal,ResolvedIsolatedComModules,_DeploymentLooseManifestFile,NativeReferenceFile).
       CollectFilesFromAllExtraReferenceFiles:
         Gather all files from Project items @(AllExtraReferenceFiles). Adding:
       CollectFilesFrom_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectory:
         Gather all files from Project items @(_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectoryAlways,_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectory). Adding:
         bin\ApplicationInsights.config;bin\roslyn\csc.exe;bin\roslyn\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll;bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll;bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll;bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll;bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets;bin\roslyn\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets;bin\roslyn\System.Collections.Immutable.dll;bin\roslyn\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll;bin\roslyn\vbc.exe;bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe;bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe.config
       CollectFilesFrom_binDeployableAssemblies:
         Gather all files from Project items @(_binDeployableAssemblies). Adding:
       PipelineCollectFilesPhase:
         Publish Pipeline Collect Files Phase
       ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol:
         Exclude All Debug Symbols
       PreTransformWebConfig:
         Found The following for Config tranformation:
         Web.config
         Skip copying Web.config to obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\original\Web.config, File obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\original\Web.config is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1\Web.Release.config to obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\assist\Web.config, File obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\assist\Web.config is up to date
       TransformWebConfigCore:
       Skipping target "TransformWebConfigCore" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
       PostTransformWebConfig:
         Transformed Web.config using C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
       PipelineTransformPhase:
         Publish Pipeline Transform Phase
       CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage:
         Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
         obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
         Skip copying bin\TestWebProject1.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\TestWebProject1.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\TestWebProject1.dll is up to date
         Skip copying Content\bootstrap.css to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\bootstrap.css, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\bootstrap.css is up to date
         Skip copying Content\bootstrap.min.css to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\bootstrap.min.css, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\bootstrap.min.css is up to date
         Skip copying favicon.ico to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\favicon.ico, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\favicon.ico is up to date
         Skip copying fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg is up to date
         Skip copying Global.asax to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Owin.1.0\lib\net40\Owin.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Owin.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Owin.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.Helpers.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.Helpers.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.Optimization.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.Optimization.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.Razor.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.Razor.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.WebPages.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.WebPages.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib\WebGrease.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\WebGrease.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\WebGrease.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1\ApplicationInsights.config to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\ApplicationInsights.config, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\ApplicationInsights.config is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\csc.exe to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\csc.exe, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\csc.exe is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\System.Collections.Immutable.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\System.Collections.Immutable.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\System.Collections.Immutable.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\vbc.exe to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\vbc.exe, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\vbc.exe is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe is up to date
         Skip copying C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\VBCSCompiler.exe.config to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe.config, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\roslyn\VBCSCompiler.exe.config is up to date
         Skip copying obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config, File obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config is up to date
       PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder:
         Publish Pipeline Deploy phase Stage PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder
       WebFileSystemPublish:
         Creating directory "\depkcfs\data\APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT\WORK\ADS\Jack Moore\TestWebProject".
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets(93,5): Error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "\depkcfs\data\APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT\WORK\ADS\Jack Moore\TestWebProject". The user name or password is incorrect.
     2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets(93,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "\depkcfs\data\APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT\WORK\ADS\Jack Moore\TestWebProject". The user name or password is incorrect. [C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets(93,5): error MSB3191:  [C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1.csproj]
     2>Done Building Project "C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
     1>Done Building Project "C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1.sln" (BUILD;Publish target(s)) -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
       "C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1.sln" (BUILD;Publish target) (1) ->
       "C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
       (WebFileSystemPublish target) -> 
         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0*****`

```
\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets(93,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "\\depkcfs\data\APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT\WORK\ADS\Jack Moore\TestWebProject". The user name or password is incorrect`***.**
```

[C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1.csproj]
       C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets(93,5): error MSB3191:  [C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\s\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1\TestWebProject1.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:01.20
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

---

Finishing task: VSBuild

---

---

Starting task: Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

---

Set workingFolder to default: C:\DEPBuildAgent\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.12
found 0 files

---

Finishing task: CopyFiles

---

---

Starting task: Publish Artifact: drop

---

Set workingFolder to default: C:\DEPBuildAgent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.27
Max Concurrent Uploads 2, Max Creators 1
Found 0 files to upload.
Created 0 files without uploading content. Total files processed 0
Uploaded artifact 'C:\DEPBuildAgent_work\6\a' to container folder 'drop' of build 128.
Associated artifact 62 with build 128

---

Finishing task: PublishBuildArtifacts

---

Task VSBuild failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
Worker Worker-4658dbb2-e9d7-4d73-a1d9-57d2de4008f0 finished running job 4658dbb2-e9d7-4d73-a1d9-57d2de4008f0

---

Finishing Build

---

Comment: which version of TFS are you using? Are you using XAML build or the new build system?

Comment: Please share entire log, as well as your MSBuild argument. Also, you need to check the permission which runs the build agent to see if it has correct permission. Try to log on your build agent machine, and use MSBuild command line to deploy your project, to see whether you can deploy it.

Comment: In addition, stop the website deployed before in IIS, and have another try.

Comment: I'm using TFS 2015. It's using the regular build definitions, not XAML as I could not get that to work either. I haven't tried the msbuild argument from the server, but I will when I find out how.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have an issue I came across on my first publishing via WebDeploy.

Add in /p:UserName="NameOnServerForSiteYou'repusblishingTo" /p:Password:YourPassword in your publishing.xml